# Parse JSON object w/o using identifier

Tags: json, parsing

I get an array of objects returned from a AJAX request in the form:

```
[Object { M_ID_mt="9"}, Object { M_ID_mt="12"}, 5 more...]
```

But because the identifier (`M_ID_mt` in this example) will change depending on the data returned, I want to parse this array in a loop without using the identifier.

Is there a way to pull the "data" (`9`, `12`, ...) from each object w/o dereferencing using the identifier?

Comment: That is not JSON. Please include the actual JSON or remove "JSON" from your question and the tags.

Comment: I'm sorry, your right, that is how Firebug displays the value.

Answer (score -2):

If you really receive JSON, such as

```
[{"M_ID_mt":"9"},{"M_ID_mt":"12"}]
```

there is libraries to parse/query json, may be one would do the job:

- http://jsonselect.org
- http://www.jsoniq.org/
- https://github.com/mmckegg/json-query
- ...

Comment: None of these will parse the data from the question.